# Is there a possibility to add an additional schema field to GraphQL's response at runtime?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graphql

I would like to add an additional field from *graphql.schema* to response of the GraphQL query if this value isn't null, thus it must be done at runtime to check it. I tried with implementing *Instrumentation* interface and overriding the *instrumentExecutionResult()* method so far. Any other ideas?

Comment: Please add more info

Comment: Im using GraphQL with Spring Boot. I have schema.graphql file with many fields.
Application runs. I send query to the server via Postman. Now while collecting data, based on request, if specific variable isn' null, then I want it also in my response despite the fact it wasn't in request.
Example:
graphql query
*{
   id
   name
}*

should act as:
*{
  id
  name
  if(!null) extraValue
}*